# Beginner C language: Problem with condition in while loop... same logic different result

Tags: c

My code should delete all vowels from the string that i give. But it does not delete if the vowel is the last character of the string.

`#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a string :\n");
    gets(str);
    int len=strlen(str);
    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c",str[i]);
    if(str[i]=='A'||str[i]=='a'||str[i]=='E'||str[i]=='e'||str[i]=='I'||str[i]=='i'||str[i]=='O'||str[i]=='o'||str[i]=='U'||str[i]=='u')
        printf("\b");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}`

Like if i provide the string Hello it prints Hllo where it should print Hll ...But if i change the while condition to (i

Comment: What happens when you step through it in the debugger?

Comment: [`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) is deprecated because it is vulnerable to buffer overflow. Imagine what happens if it read more than 100 characters from `stdin`. Use [`gets_s()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) or [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: @axiac This is not what causes OP's problem. Still +1 (maybe +100), you highlight a very important issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess printing \b doesn’t do what you think it does. It does not delete the last printed character, it just prints an additional ‘backspace’ character, which on *some* output devices (such as console) moves backwards by one character. (Then, the *next* character overwrites the one you wanted ‘deleted’.)

Don’t do that. Instead, move the ‘if’ statement so that you don’t print those vowels in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
int i=0;
char str[100];
printf("Enter a string :\n");
fgets(str,100, stdin);
int len=strlen(str);
while(str[i]!='\0')
{

if(str[i]=='A'||str[i]=='a'||str[i]=='E'||str[i]=='e'||str[i]=='I'||str[i]=='i'||str[i]=='O'||str[i]=='o'||str[i]=='U'||str[i]=='u'){
    continue;
}else{
     printf("%c",str[i]);
}
    i++;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Not really. The 'continue' will cause this program to get stuck on an infinite loop as soon as it encounters a vowel.